# Going from an SqlParameter to the SQL type

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql, sqlparameter

I have an SqlParameter object and I want to get the equivalent sql for the data type, e.g. `varchar(50)`, `int`, `decimal(1, 2)`

I've started looking at building it dynamically by switching on the `SqlDbType` to determine if i need to use the Size property etc however this is very long-winded and error prone.

Is there a way of doing this built into the .net framework?

Comment: What are you doing that requires you to know this? 99% of the time you can let the driver deal with this. Show your code...

Comment: I've got an SqlCommand with a select statement (and parameters). I want to create an sql command that will create a stored procedure that has the same parameters and returns the same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQL Server Type Mappings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716729.aspx) has the information you require.

> I've started looking at building it dynamically by switching on the `SqlDbType` to determine if i need to use the Size property etc however this is very long-winded and error prone.

It's unlikely you can improve upon this, the page says this much:

> **SQL Server and the .NET Framework are based on different type systems**. For example, the .NET Framework Decimal structure has a maximum scale of 28, whereas the SQL Server decimal and numeric data types have a maximum scale of 38

For the example of `Decimal` and `decimal`, you could always fix the scale at 28. That is, always take the highest precision required and do not try to vary it.

Comment: I understand what you're saying (given a .net type I don't have enough info to get an sql type), but I've got an `SqlParameter`, which has information re. size/scale/precision so I should be able to get the exact sql declaration. I suppose what I should take from this answer is that I'll need to implement this myself.